# LI height same as UL

Tags: html, css

Hi I am wondering how come my UL is 38px height yet the LI does not fit 100% height.

```
ul#ordermenu{
    height:38px !important;
    width:100% !important;
    line-height:38px;
}

ul#ordermenu li
{
height:38px !important;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 100px;
color:#000;
line-height:38px;
font-size:20px;
}

ul#ordermenu li:last-child {
    padding-right:-100px;
}
ul#ordermenu li.active
{
height:38px !important;
line-height:38px;
background: #e6f0a3; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e6f0a3 0%, #d2e638 50%, #c3d825 51%, #dbf043 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e6f0a3), color-stop(50%,#d2e638), color-stop(51%,#c3d825), color-stop(100%,#dbf043)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e6f0a3 0%,#d2e638 50%,#c3d825 51%,#dbf043 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #e6f0a3 0%,#d2e638 50%,#c3d825 51%,#dbf043 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #e6f0a3 0%,#d2e638 50%,#c3d825 51%,#dbf043 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e6f0a3 0%,#d2e638 50%,#c3d825 51%,#dbf043 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e6f0a3', endColorstr='#dbf043',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

My HTML code

```
 <ul id="ordermenu">
        <li class="active">Items</li>
        <li>Checkout Status</li>
        <li>Postage Details</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: maybe because you've defined them as not important?

Comment: ?? what do you mean by that

Comment: Try `position: inline-block` for the `li` css declaration.

Comment: @Timmy `!important` is used in CSS to indicate that a rule should override all others in the cascade.

Comment: lol, not important, that must be a joke

Comment: It is indeed a joke, forgive me if i offended lol :p A fellow student said the same thing in a lecture one time and I couldn't help but bring it up here. My bad =)

Comment: @Timmy nothing wrong with a bit of humour, gave me a laugh at least

Comment: Can I inquire as to the logic of using a `ul` that has it's height fixed to the same height as it's only `li`? Why use a list?

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `li` is not 38px tall is because of the `display: inline` on `ul#ordermenu li`

Try this:

```
#ordermenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 38px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a height to inline elements, as you are doing for `ul#ordermenu li`. Try changing the display property to 'inline-block'. This will allow you to give the list-items a specific height while still arranging them horizontally.